# mySQL: How do I do multiple subqueries and group by for use with datatables?

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, datatables, subquery

I want to generate the following data set for use with DataTables.  For the filtering and sorting to work properly, using JOINS instead of subqueries is difficult, if not impossible (as far as I can tell).

Applicant Name, Position, Interviewer, Interview 1 Score, Interview 2 Score, Demo. Score, Interview Date

Here is how the data is stored in mySQL (simplified version):

applicant_scores table

```
id  applicant_id    interviewer_id  score_type  score   datetime_recorded
 1             2                 3  Interview 1    80   2013-04-23 09:35:48
 2             2                45  Interview 1    70   2013-04-23 10:14:23
 3             2                 3  Interview 2    85   2013-04-23 09:35:48
 4             2                45  Interview 2    77   2013-04-23 10:14:23
 5             2                 3  Demonstration  76   2013-04-23 09:35:48
 6             3                45  Interview 1    79   2013-04-23 10:14:23
 7             3                 3  Interview 1    86   2013-04-23 09:35:48
 8             3                45  Interview 2    92   2013-04-23 10:14:23
```

applicants table

```
id  first_name  last_name
 2  John        Doe 
 3  Jane        Doe
```

interviewer table

```
id  first_name  last_name
 3  Santa       Claus
45  Fred        Flintstone
```

applicant_positions table

```
position_id   applicant_id
          1              2
          1              3
```

positions table

```
id  title                 
 1  Advanced mySQL Programmer
```

I've tried everything that I can think of, but I'm having trouble grouping scores by interviewer and applicant correctly.  What I expect to see is:

```
Applicant Name   Position                   Interviewer   Interview 1 Score  Interview 2 Score   Demo. Score  Interview Date
      John Doe   Advanced mySQL Programmer  Santa Claus                  80                 85            76      2013-04-23
      John Doe   Advanced mySQL Programmer  Fred Flintstone              70                 77                    2013-04-23
      Jane Doe   Advanced mySQL Programmer  Santa Claus                  86                                       2013-04-23
      Jane Doe   Advanced mySQL Programmer  Fred Flintstone              79                 92                    2013-04-23
```

Here is my current query which gives zero results:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 
       CONCAT( a.first_name, ' ', a.last_name), 
       p.title,
       CONCAT( i.first_name, ' ', i.last_name),
      (SELECT score FROM applicant_scores s, applicants a WHERE s.applicant_id = a.id AND s.score_type = 'Interview 1') as score_1, 
      (SELECT score FROM applicant_scores s, applicants a WHERE s.applicant_id = a.id AND s.score_type = 'Interview 2') as score_2, 
      (SELECT score FROM applicant_scores s, applicants a WHERE s.applicant_id = a.id AND s.score_type = 'Demonstration') as score_3, 
      (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(datetime_recorded, '%m-%d-%Y') FROM applicant_scores s, applicants a WHERE s.applicant_id = a.id) as interview_date
 FROM applicants a, positions p, interviewers i, applicant_scores s
 WHERE s.applicant_id = a.id AND i.id = s.interviewer_id
 GROUP BY i.id
```

Here is the server side ajax code that is being used to feed DataTables... Here is info on how to create server side script for DataTables - http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

```
<?php
    /* Database connection information */
    $gaSql['user']       = "";
    $gaSql['password']   = "";
    $gaSql['db']         = "";
    $gaSql['server']     = "";

    $q1="'";
    $q2='"';

    $name = "CONCAT( ".$q2."<input type='hidden' id='name' value='".$q2.", LOWER(a.last_name), ' ', LOWER(a.first_name), ".$q2."'><input type='hidden' id='applicant_id' value='".$q2.", a.id, ".$q2."'><a href='applicant_details.php?id=".$q2.", a.id, ".$q2."'><img src='img/search.png' border='0'></a> &nbsp;".$q2.", a.last_name, ', ', a.first_name )";

    $interviewer = "CONCAT( ".$q2."<input type='hidden' id='name' value='".$q2.", LOWER(u.lastname), ' ', LOWER(u.firstname), ".$q2."'><input type='hidden' id='interviewer_id' value='".$q2.", i.id, ".$q2."'><a href='interviewer_details.php?id=".$q2.", i.id, ".$q2."'><img src='img/search.png' border='0'></a> &nbsp;".$q2.", u.lastname, ', ', u.firstname )";

    $int_1_score = "(SELECT score FROM applicant_scores s, applicants a WHERE s.applicant_id = a.id AND s.score_type = 'Interview 1' AND s.interviewer_id = i.id) as score_1";
    $int_2_score = "(SELECT score FROM applicant_scores s, applicants a WHERE s.applicant_id = a.id AND s.score_type = 'Interview 2' AND s.interviewer_id = i.id) as score_2";
    $demo_score = "(SELECT score FROM applicant_scores s, applicants a WHERE s.applicant_id = a.id AND s.score_type = 'Demonstration' AND s.interviewer_id = i.id) as score_3";

    $interview_date = "(SELECT DATE_FORMAT(datetime_recorded, '%m-%d-%Y') FROM applicant_scores s, applicants a WHERE s.applicant_id = a.id) as interview_date";

    $aColumns = array($name, 'p.title', $interviewer, $int_1_score, $int_2_score, $demo_score, $interview_date);

    /* Indexed column (used for fast and accurate table cardinality) */
    $sIndexColumn = "id";
    $sIndexTable = "formtemplates";

    /* DB table to use */
    $sTable = "applicants a, positions p, interviewers i, applicant_scores s, users u";

    $sWhere = " WHERE s.applicant_id = a.id AND i.id = s.interviewer_id AND u.id = i.user_id";

    $sGroupBy = " GROUP BY i.id";

    /* 
     * MySQL connection
     */
    $gaSql['link'] =  mysql_pconnect( $gaSql['server'], $gaSql['user'], $gaSql['password']  ) or
        die( 'Could not open connection to server' );

    mysql_select_db( $gaSql['db'], $gaSql['link'] ) or 
        die( 'Could not select database '. $gaSql['db'] );


    /* 
     * Paging
     */
    $sLimit = "";
    if ( isset( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ) && $_GET['iDisplayLength'] != '-1' )
    {
        $sLimit = "LIMIT ".mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ).", ".
            mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['iDisplayLength'] );
    }

    /*
     * Ordering
     */
    if ( isset( $_GET['iSortCol_0'] ) )
    {
        $sOrder = " ORDER BY  ";
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<intval( $_GET['iSortingCols'] ) ; $i++ )
        {
            if ( $_GET[ 'bSortable_'.intval($_GET['iSortCol_'.$i]) ] == "true" )
            {
                if(stripos($aColumns[ intval( $_GET['iSortCol_'.$i] ) ], "c.name", 1) >= 1){
                    $sOrder .= "c.name ".mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['sSortDir_'.$i] ).", ";
                }elseif(stripos($aColumns[ intval( $_GET['iSortCol_'.$i] ) ], "t.firstName", 1) >= 1){
                    $sOrder .= "t.firstName ".mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['sSortDir_'.$i] ).", ";
                }elseif(stripos($aColumns[ intval( $_GET['iSortCol_'.$i] ) ], "d.shortName", 1) >= 1){
                    $sOrder .= "d.shortName ".mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['sSortDir_'.$i] ).", ";
                }else{
                    $sOrder .= $aColumns[ intval( $_GET['iSortCol_'.$i] ) ]."
                    ".mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['sSortDir_'.$i] ) .", ";
                }
            }
        }

        $sOrder = substr_replace( $sOrder, "", -2 );
        if ( $sOrder == "ORDER BY" )
        {
            $sOrder = "";
        }
    }


    /* 
     * Filtering
     * NOTE this does not match the built-in DataTables filtering which does it
     * word by word on any field. It's possible to do here, but concerned about efficiency
     * on very large tables, and MySQL's regex functionality is very limited
     */

    //define columns to filter on
    $aFcolumns = array( 'u.username', 'u.firstname', 'u.lastname', "REPLACE (g.status, 'OUT_FOR_SIGNATURE', 'WAITING')");

    if ( $_GET['sSearch'] != "" )
    {
        //$sWhere .= "WHERE (";
        $sWhere .= " AND (";
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aFcolumns) ; $i++ )
        {
            $sWhere .= $aFcolumns[$i]." LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['sSearch'] )."%' OR ";
        }
        $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
        $sWhere .= ')';
    }


    /* Individual column filtering */
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aFcolumns) ; $i++ )
    {
        if ( $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" && $_GET['sSearch_'.$i] != '' )
        {
            if ( $sWhere == "" )
            {
                $sWhere = "WHERE ";
            }
            else
            {
                $sWhere .= " AND ";
            }
            $sWhere .= $aFcolumns[$i]." LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sSearch_'.$i])."%' ";
        }
    }


    /*
     * SQL queries
     * Get data to display
     */
    $sQuery = "
        SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ".str_replace(" , ", " ", implode(", ", $aColumns))."
         FROM   $sTable
        $sWhere
        $sGroupBy       
        $sOrder 
        $sLimit
    ";

    //echo $sQuery;  die();  //for firebug debugging

    $rResult = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or die(mysql_error());

    /* Data set length after filtering */
    $sQuery = "
        SELECT FOUND_ROWS()
    ";
    $rResultFilterTotal = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or die(mysql_error());
    $aResultFilterTotal = mysql_fetch_array($rResultFilterTotal);
    $iFilteredTotal = $aResultFilterTotal[0];

    /* Total data set length */
    $sQuery = "
        SELECT COUNT(".$sIndexColumn.")
        FROM   $sIndexTable
    ";
    $rResultTotal = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or die(mysql_error());
    $aResultTotal = mysql_fetch_array($rResultTotal);
    $iTotal = $aResultTotal[0];

    /*
     * Output
     */
    $output = array(
        "sEcho" => intval($_GET['sEcho']),
        "iTotalRecords" => $iTotal,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $iFilteredTotal,
        "aaData" => array()
    );

    while ( $aRow = mysql_fetch_array( $rResult ) )
    {
        $row = array();
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
        {
            if ( $aColumns[$i] != ' ' )
            {
                /* General output */
                $row[] = $aRow[$i];
            }
        }

        //add another row for buttons
        //$row[] = "<div style='float:right;'><span style='padding-right:2px;'><a href=''><img src='global_img\user_info.png' border='0'></a></span><span style='padding-right:2px;'><a href=''><img src='global_img\user_edit.png' border='0'></a></span><span style='padding-right:0px;'><a href=''><img src='global_img\user_delete.png' border='0'></a></span></div>";

        $output['aaData'][] = $row;
    }

    echo json_encode( $output );
?>
```

I modified the server side script to attempt to use the solution provided by bluefeet and the following is the generated query:

```
        SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS concat(a.first_name, ' ', a.last_name), p.title, CONCAT(i1.first_name, ' ', i1.last_name), max(case when ac.score_type='Interview 1' then ac.score else '' end), max(case when ac.score_type='Interview 2' then ac.score else '' end), max(case when ac.score_type='Demonstration' then ac.score else '' end), DATE_FORMAT(ac.datetime_recorded, '%m-%d-%Y')
         FROM   applicants a
         inner join applicant_positions ap on a.id = ap.applicant_id inner join positions p on ap.position_id = p.id inner join applicant_scores ac on a.id = ac.applicant_id inner join interviewers i1 on ac.interviewer_id = i1.id 
         GROUP BY concat(a.first_name, ' ', a.last_name), p.title, CONCAT(i1.first_name, ' ', i1.last_name), DATE_FORMAT(ac.datetime_recorded, '%m-%d-%Y')      
         ORDER BY  concat(a.first_name, ' ', a.last_name)
                    asc 
        LIMIT 0, 500
```

This gives me an empty result set though.  HELP?

Comment: Your first query is not valid (maybe a typo?). It has `AND u.id = i.user_id` but no table `u` defined.

Comment: Yeah. That was an older version of the query.  I made the correction.

Comment: And now you are missing a join condition on `positions p`

Comment: I finally got it working... but the search and sorting features of datatables no longer work... i need to spend a little more time on this and I'll post a solution once it's a but more finalized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were definitely on the right track to get the result.

You are currently missing a few joins in your query. You need to join the `applicants` to the `positions` using the `applicant_positions` table. You can also add a join to the `applicant_scores` table which will let you use an aggregate function with a `CASE` to get the columns containing the Interview/Demo Scores:

```
select 
  concat(a.first_name, ' ', a.last_name) ApplicantName,
  p.title Position,
  CONCAT(i1.first_name, ' ', i1.last_name) Interviewer,
  max(case when ac.score_type='Interview 1' then ac.score else '' end) Interview1Score,
  max(case when ac.score_type='Interview 2' then ac.score else '' end) Interview2Score,
  max(case when ac.score_type='Demonstration' then ac.score else '' end) DemoScore,
  DATE_FORMAT(ac.datetime_recorded, '%m-%d-%Y') InterviewDate
from applicants a
inner join applicant_positions ap
  on a.id = ap.applicant_id
inner join positions p
  on ap.position_id = p.id
inner join applicant_scores ac
  on a.id = ac.applicant_id
inner join interviewers i1
  on ac.interviewer_id = i1.id
group by concat(a.first_name, ' ', a.last_name),
  p.title,
  CONCAT(i1.first_name, ' ', i1.last_name),
  DATE_FORMAT(ac.datetime_recorded, '%m-%d-%Y');
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9fe06/17). This give the result:

```
| APPLICANTNAME |                  POSITION |     INTERVIEWER | INTERVIEW1SCORE | INTERVIEW2SCORE | DEMOSCORE | INTERVIEWDATE |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|      Jane Doe | Advanced mySQL Programmer | Fred Flintstone |              79 |              92 |           |    04-23-2013 |
|      Jane Doe | Advanced mySQL Programmer |     Santa Claus |              86 |                 |           |    04-23-2013 |
|      John Doe | Advanced mySQL Programmer | Fred Flintstone |              70 |              77 |           |    04-23-2013 |
|      John Doe | Advanced mySQL Programmer |     Santa Claus |              80 |              85 |        76 |    04-23-2013 |
```

Comment: Is there any way to accomplish this without using JOINs?  I don't think this will work with DataTables.

Comment: @compcentral What join do you want to exclude? Your current query is using Joins. You have to JOIN the tables to be able to associate the data with each applicant.

Comment: What? @compcentral You also have joins in your query (not explicit but implicit) but still joins.

Comment: @compcentral soooooo based on your comment i'm assuming you mean DataTables the javascript utility ... you return the value from the server (which performs the actual retrieval with the joins), and give it to the javascript formatted however it needs to be formatted for the the utility to consume.

Comment: @swasheck Correct.  I will update the question with the server side code that is generating the query so everyone understands what I'm trying to do.

Comment: attempting to use your solution, the sql generated gives an error: Unknown column 'i1.first_name' in 'field list'

Comment: @compcentral Well I used the `interviewers` table that you posted initially with the columns `first_name`, `last_name` does that table have those columns?  If not, then you will need to alter the code to use the correct column names.

Comment: ok.. I corrected the table structure (was using firstname instead or first_name).  I don't get any errors, but the result set is empty.

Comment: @compcentral Depending on what you want, you might need to use a `LEFT JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN` between the tables.

Comment: When I run the resultant query I get the correct results in SQL fiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9fe06/18) but not using the actual DB, so I must be overlooking something simple.

Comment: @compcentral It's difficult because I cannot see your actual DB, this query should be working. My suggestion would be to start with a one join initially, then start adding more tables.  It will help debug it in your DB

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  CONCAT(b.first_name, ' ', b.last_Name) Applicant_Name,
        CONCAT(c.first_name, ' ', c.last_Name) Interviewer_Name,
        e.Title,
        MAX(CASE WHEN a.score_type = 'Interview 1' THEN a.score END) `Interview 1 Score`,
        MAX(CASE WHEN a.score_type = 'Interview 2' THEN a.score END) `Interview 2 Score`,
        MAX(CASE WHEN a.score_type = 'Demonstration' THEN a.score END) `Demonstration Score`,
        MAX(DATE(a.datetime_recorded)) `Interview Date`
FROM    applicant_scores a
        INNER JOIN applicants b
            ON a.applicant_ID = b.ID
        INNER JOIN interviewer c
            ON a.interviewer_ID = c.id
        INNER JOIN applicant_positions d
            ON a.applicant_ID = d.applicant_ID
        INNER JOIN positions e
            ON d.position_ID = e.ID
GROUP   BY  CONCAT(b.first_name, ' ', b.last_Name),
            CONCAT(c.first_name, ' ', c.last_Name),
            e.Title
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/da51f/3)

Comment: Is there any way to accomplish this without using JOINs?  I don't think this will work with DataTables.

Comment: No. Because the the values needed on the columns came from the other tables. Don't think about doing this in correlated subquery because mysql is not good enough on subquery.

Comment: see my revised question... How would you suggest that I make this work then?